# someone has stolen my phone

Tags: google-account

someone has stolen my phone and at the phone has no service right now so I have no idea what to do I cant get In to my g-mail and I really need to get into it  but I cant recover it because the reset cods are sent to that phone  and I cant remember what email I used as the back up email so what can I do I cant even get in to gmail to recover my apps, pics , contacts , (ect) is there anyway at all I could really use the help thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take your laptop/desktop computer and see your history browser from Google Chrome and/or Firefox to remember what was the name of your email accounts. Otherwise, if you often use a friend's computer, you could request him/her if his/her laptop recorded your email accounts